# Multi website category url issue in magento 2

Tags: magento2, multi-website, base-url

I have 2 website Retail and wholesale. Both the websites have same categories.
Retail website takes proper base url.https://5iallk0uwem1coeq.mojostratus.io/
For the wholesale website i have set the base url as https://wholesale-5iallk0uwem1coeq.mojostratus.io/ but still it is taking the base url for the retail store.

You can refer https://wholesale-5iallk0uwem1coeq.mojostratus.io/ url and check the categories in menu and the footer links.

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed some issue like that when I was working with my new stores. At the end I saw some information were missing in the core data.

Not sure this is what you missed, but you should take a look at this request output

`Select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'`

This is where the url is supposed to be set in the value column.